# Is it possible to get codacy to check usage of imported modules?

Tags: github, pylint, codacy, pylintrc

I have an ever-growing list of modules to ignore in my pylintrc:

```
ignored-modules=anytree,apsw,bs4,cachecontrol,dateutil,inflect,matplotlib,markdown,munch,MySQLdb,pytest,pytz,requests_oauthlib,rrule,seaborn,titlecase,untangle,googleapiclient
```

because otherwise codacy will fail my pull request.

Is there a way to have codacy know about these (pip) modules?

Failing that is there a way to say "ignore these on codacy checks but don't ignore them during local runs of pylint"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that there is a [`.codacy-pylintrc`](https://gist.github.com/RDCH106/ba9626186fb069745f8de98b18a39ce3) file suggests it is possible to configure [`codacy-pylint`](https://github.com/codacy/codacy-pylint) to use a dedicate `pylintrc` file (with the  `-rcfile=.codacy-pylintrc` option)

As  opposed to a local run of `pylint`, which will look by default for a regular `~/.pylintrc` file (where you don't have to ignore those modules).

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851782/is-it-possible-to-get-codacy-to-check-usage-of-imported-modules/47913949#comment82849221_47913949), that also means you can do the reverse:

- make sure your local run of `pylint` uses a custom file (with the `-rcfile=xxx` option),
- while `codacy-pylint` would use the default `.pylintrc` file

Comment: Awesome, this is a start. I don't think it's going to read a .codacy-pylintrc that I just dump in my project because that file is from their Docker instance they use to run pylint (?) but I've jammed one in for a test and sent a PR …

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker Or do the reverse: make sure your local run of pylint use a custom file (with the `-rcfile=xxx` option), while codacy-pylint would use the default file.

Comment: Man, I feel slow :) I'll do that. Thanks!